# Material UI Dialog blinks on click on iOS (iPhone)

Tags: ios, reactjs, material-ui

We are using Material UI Dialog in our web app. Most users access our site via iPhone devices. When the dialog is shown you can click on empty space and cause a blink to occur on iPhone devices. Is there a way to remove that blink (opaque black filter) from those Dialogs? It doesnt do that on things outside the dialogs.